# Using fractions in Verilog-a

Tags: matlab, verilog

In MATLAB:

```
expp = (1/2)*exp(Vgt/(Etaf*Vth));
```

this code works well. The minimum value of `expp` is about `3.5e-18`.

However in Verilog-a, `expp` values are always `0`. I checked `Vgt`, `Etaf` and `Vth`. These variables are calculated well.

What's the problem in this code?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out why. The problem is `(1/2)` in the code. In Verilog A, I have to write the code like this:

```
expp = 0.5*exp(Vgt/(Etaf*Vth));
```

Comment: actually in many programming languages '1/2' is an integer division resulting in '0'. you need '0.5' or something like '1.0/2' to deal with  floating point.